# How can I nest directives dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, angular-ui-router

still learning Angular and I am working with routing.

My Task: I got an example project where I got to html structures which are shared by multiple sites. FOr Example: There is a route definition like

```
.state('start', {
            url: '/start',
            templateUrl: 'app/start/start.html',
            controller: 'StartController',
            controllerAs: 'start'

        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'app/start/start.html',
            controller: 'StartController',
            controllerAs: 'start',
        })
        .state('logout', {
            url: '/logout',
            templateUrl: 'app/start/start.html',
            controller: 'StartController',
            controllerAs: 'start'
        })
```

Those routes are using the same template and controller, because the got a frame of items arround the content and differ in one html tag only, which also haves different functionality.

The template (app/start/start.html) is like that:

```
<div layout="vertical" layout-fill>

  <md-content layout="column" flex>

    <div id="ContentHeader" layout="row">
      <div layout="column">1</div>
      <div layout="column" flex>2</div>
      <div layout="column">3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="ContentBody" layout="row" flex>

      <dynamic-template></dynamic-template>

    </div>

    <div id="ContentFooter" layout="row">2</div>

  </md-content>

</div>
```

Now I would like to switch the directive/content dynamically for

```
<dynamic-template></dynamic-template>
```

The login / logoff and start route are using different directive/controller...

What is the best practice to nest directives dynamically?

Regards, n00n

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that, the purpose of the _Dynamic Template_ is to show different content depending on what the User has triggered such as an About Page or a Contact Page?

Comment: Where do you store your "login" state? Just parse that state into your directive and handle it with a software switch.

Comment: @user2340824 Thats it, got 2 templates containing a div which differs on the routes ... how to solve it?

Comment: @n00n Did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use [Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views)

Idea is to have multiple named views in your template. These named views can then be set differently, per state.

If we take your example, here what you would need to do:

template:

```
<div layout="vertical" layout-fill>

  <md-content layout="column" flex>

    <div id="ContentHeader" layout="row">
      <div layout="column">1</div>
      <div layout="column" flex>2</div>
      <div layout="column">3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="ContentBody" layout="row" flex>

      <div ui-view="dynamic"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="ContentFooter" layout="row">2</div>

  </md-content>

</div>
```

Here we have added new named `ui-view` as `dynamic`.

Router:

```
.state('start', {
        url: '/start',
        views:{
                 "":{
                     templateUrl: 'app/start/start.html',
                     controller: 'StartController',
                     controllerAs: 'start'},
                "dynamic":{
                     templateUrl: 'app/start/myCustomStartView.html',
                     controller: 'StartController',
                     controllerAs: 'start'}

        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            views:{
                 "":{
                     templateUrl: 'app/start/start.html',
                     controller: 'StartController',
                     controllerAs: 'start'},
                "dynamic":{
                     templateUrl: 'app/start/myCustomLoginView.html',
                     controller: 'StartController',
                     controllerAs: 'start'}
        })
        .state('logout', {
            url: '/logout',
            views:{
                 "":{
                     templateUrl: 'app/start/start.html',
                     controller: 'StartController',
                     controllerAs: 'start'},
                "dynamic":{
                     templateUrl: 'app/start/myCustomLogoutView.html',
                     controller: 'StartController',
                     controllerAs: 'start'}
        })
```

Here, we have added `views` definition to each state. The views name determine which ui-view we are targeting. So, view named with "dynamic" will target `<div ui-view="dynamic"></div>`. We can then controller what template is to be populated in dynamic view by changing the template.